# How to modify build.gradle file programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, eclipse-jdt

Is there any way to add dependency to a `gradle` or `maven` project programmatically ? I am trying to modify a java file using eclipse JDT. One of my changes requires a method from `apache-commons`. So I have to check programmatically whether the library is already included and if not I have to add the dependency. Is there any way or tool that helps me?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would **hate** it if an IDE plugin modified my build behind my back. I want to choose the dependencies I use. I want to decide how and where to declare them. Not to mention that adding a dependency just because you need a method isn't the wisest thing to do.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea...The question is what kind of real problem are you trying to solve? If a dependency is missing just add to `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`..? Using Eclipse there is a dialog if you have opened a pom file on a tab "Dependencies" where is a Button "Add"...?

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify build file, like `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` for that needs. I think, it's a better idea to check if the library is in the project's classpath and if it's not - gently ask a developer to add it. That's how, for example, generating of `toString` works in IDEA: if certain libraries are available in the project corresponding options become available: [image: <code>toString()</code> options]

Comment: What if we're not in Android Studio?